# how many times do I have to include the $(document) .ready (function() in my external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble figuring out how to link my javascript externally. I'm not sure what the issue is but inline the script works fine. However, when I throw the script into a .js file and try to link it from a `<script type="text/javascript">` it doesn't work at all.

I have several instances of the same function going on (because it's something that occurs in multiple sections, which is different content but the same type of function of a hidden div being shown when another element is clicked).

I don't know if it's because I'm including `$(document).ready(function()` too many times or not enough, or what. I HAVE to place the `<script type="text/javascript">` in the body because I do not have access to the head section of my pages (editing inside of a WSIWYG EzPublisher mce type editor).

My script is too long to place in stackoverflow, but I'll perhaps post it on a web server that I do control if need be.

But my nutshell question is how many times should I be including the `$(document) .ready(function()` in my external `.js` file?

Comment: 0 times. it isn't a requirement for code to work.

Comment: here's a link to the script:
http://j2kwebs.com/scripts/togglePlusButtons.js

Comment: one IF you call your custom script in the `<head>` section. If you load your custom script at the bottom of the page, you don't even have to include it.

Comment: Isn't question: "How many handlers I push to $(document).ready event?"

Comment: @Jay: what is your problem in the first place, you should write what error you are getting ?

Comment: no error, it just dosn't work at all. The script should work like on this page: http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/09_01_13/test-text
 (see the circles with plus signs in them that expand content when clicked, and vice versa when clicked again)..but when I take the script out and load and link it to an external js file, it stops working completely

Answer (score 1):

One Time is enough , if you add more than one time then all of them all be executed, so it really doesnt matter .

in other words you are just adding more handlers to "ready" event.

and if you dont have any code to be inside "ready" event then no need to add it at all